# Is the simple way to store Pivot, Hub ot ListView state in session exist?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps

I'm working to port my Windows Phone Silverlight app to an Windows Universal one.

Now I try to store page UI state when a new page is opened and restore it when user navigates back.

The default behavior of the platform is the create new page on the each navigation include a back to previous page. So the result of it is lost UI state of the all previous pages.

The Internet solve it by enabling the page cache "NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;". It's really solve issue with UI state but produce new issue.

1) When you navigate forward the previous page will de used and UI will shows a wrong state.

2) In/Out page animations works bad for pages with contains a Pivot control, it animates the all PivotItems at moment the whole page content is visible until animation ends.

So the cache is not usable.

Is the other ways to save UI state exists?

Answer (score 0):

What are the elements you want to be preserved? Keep them in variables and save/restore them when navigating.

For example, if you want to keep the selected pivot item (_selectedItem`):

```
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    // Save the selected pivot item variable in the page's State dictionary.
    State["SelectedPivotItem"] = _selectedItem;

}
```

and to restore it:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
     // Restore the selected pivot item variable from the page's State dictionary.
     _selectedItem = (int)State["SelectedPivotItem"]
}
```